# Comma delimited output from SQL query

Tags: sql, csv

How can i put the result of a sql server query into a "comma delimited" format?

Comment: What database type?  Client language?  How will it be consumed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to go to `Tools->Options->Query Results` in SQL Server Management Studio and set the preferences there to output to a text file.

Then expand that and in "Result to Text" you can set the output format there.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,11324,13062#msg-13062) on the MySQL forums.

Here's the snippet.

```
SELECT a,b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.text'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql server managment studio right click on the output and you can "Save Result as" CSV

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(8000) 
SET @str = ''

SELECT @str = @str + column + ','
 FROM table SELECT @str

Comment: Really useful if the data itself contains commas.